# How to target element that has been replaced

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a drop down list. When a value is changed, I want a confirm message, asking to confirm the selected value.
a) If no, I want the value to be reset.
b) If yes, I want to replace the dropdown with a span tag with the selected value.

How do you achieve the b) part. Here's the code I wrote, but this changes the value of all span elements. Even the ones that have been set before.

This is in php. So please ignore the "" in html and the '.'

```
"<td>".
                    "<select name = 'current' id = 'test'>".
                        "<option value='None' selected>Choose a Sales Rep</option>".
                        "<option value='sales1'>Sale Rep1</option>".
                        "<option value='sales2'>Sale Rep2</option>".
                        "<option value='sales3'>Sale Rep3</option>".
                        "<option value='sales4'>Sale Rep4</option>".
                    "</select>".
                 "</td>";

<script>
        // var current = $('input[name=current]').val();    
        $("select").change(function(){
            if(confirm("Have you chosen your sales rep?")){
                var $set_value = $(this).val();
                console.log($set_value);
                $(this).replaceWith("<span></span>");
                $("span").html($set_value);

                return false;
            }else{
                $(this).val('None');
                //$.data(this, 'current',$(this).val());
            }

        })
    </script>
```

How do I target the span tag that just replaced the drop down list that I clicked on ?
Please advise.

TIA

Comment: When you say replace the dropdown list...what element are you talking about? The `select` or the specific `option`?

Answer (score 2):

You just create it before you insert it

```
var span = $('<span />', { html : $set_value });

$(this).replaceWith(span);

// if you wanted to do something to it later

span.on('click', function() { alert("wohoo") });
```